# UIButton not showing up

Tags: uibutton

I am trying to create a UIButton programmatically instead of using the interface builder. I initialize and set the button frame but the button doesn't seem to appear on the view. My code is as follows:

```
UIButton *showInfoButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0,0, 150, 150);
showInfoButton.frame = buttonFrame;
```

What am I missing? Please bear with me as I am new to iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add your `UIButton` as a subview to the `UIView` you want it to display on. Since you are building UI programmatically, you need to manually add the button as a subview to the container view.

You can do so by using this line of code:

```
[self.view addSubview:showInfoButton];
```

The button might not still appear as you are making a custom button which has a transparent background colour. In order to see the button, you can set the UIButton's backgroundColor property as follows:

```
[showInfoButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```